# PYTHON-SUDS DocumentPlugin loaded method not being called

Tags: python, exchangewebservices, suds

Pardon me if this is a trivial question. I am trying to read email using Exchange Web Service(EWS) and suds version 0.4. Since I need to modify the WSDL before suds can create the service, I am using the code below to try and modify the WSDL before suds parses it. However as far as I can tell, the plugin's loaded method is not being called.

Can anyone please advise on what I am doing wrong? I have tried using suds-ews but it seems to be out of date as I cannot insert attributes into methods.

```
class AddService(DocumentPlugin):
    # WARNING: suds hides exceptions in plugins
    def loaded(self, ctx):
        print "help"
        return ctx

client = Client("https://server/EWS/Services.wsdl",
                plugins=[AddService(),])
```

Thank you

Comment: Just my two cents, I have never had much luck with suds.  Have you tried SOAPpy or any other modules?

Comment: No, I haven't. My initial research gave me the impression that suds is probably the most up to date library.

Comment: FWIW, I successfully use a plugin in just the way you've described. Only difference between your code and mine is that I return None instead of the context, but I doubt that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because suds has already cached the parsed WSDL:

https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#PERFORMANCE

So either you can purge the temporary directory or disable caching altogether by adding a cache=None to your Client() call.